# Dynamic Querying with Pandas and pyodbc - Looking for non-string method solution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I am writing a script to dynamically query an MS Access database and return results into a pandas dataframe. There will be two parameters that will dynamically change the query.   I put together the following solution using string formatting methods. While this solution works,  I am looking for a more secure solution that doesn't use string methods.  Appreciate any knowledge you can share!

Thank You.

```
values1 = ('1','2')
values2 = ('1','2','3')

ServerName = r'pathtodb\\database.mdb'
connStr = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %ServerName
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE item in ({0}) and item2 in ({1})'
query = query.format(','.join('?' * len(values1)), ','.join('?' * len(values2)))
param_list = values1 + values2
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params=param_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: Why do you think your current method is unsecure? The actual contents of the array are still being passed as parameters. The only thing you're doing with your string functions is setting the number of parameters for each `IN`. Do you have a specific thing in mind we can prevent?

Comment: You only need to worry when the parameters are input form users. So you need to make sure their entry is a valid entry and immune to sql injection.

Comment: Being new to database queries, I stumbled across a lot of "passionate" discussions about sql injection.  Since my solution uses string methods to parse the queries, I got into a bit of "analysis paralysis" I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so as long as its my own program generating the strings, and not users, its ok. Similarly, if the parameters are user-inputs, I need to have some sort of filter that will prevent this.

Comment: I want to respectfully disagree with @krishKM. Consider a case where your program is pulling data from a CSV, database, or API and contains the string `in Bob's car` - not from a user input, but a data source. It contains a single quote. While that might not be disastrous, it would still generated an error because of the single quote. I've seen less direct attack vectors used in the past as well in very nefarious ways. SQL Injection is a complex topic without right answers (although there are many wrong answers), as there is often a consideration of time versus acceptable risk.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using temp tables, *items1* and *items2*, to hold your *item* values and then simply join for pandas import. In fact, the `JOIN` approach will be more efficient than long lists in `IN()` clauses.

```
values1 = ('1','2')
values2 = ('1','2','3')

ServerName = r'C:\pathtodb\database.mdb'
connStr = 'DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={0};'.format(ServerName)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)

cur = cnxn.cursor()

# CLEAN OUT OLD DATA AND APPEND NEW DATA
cur.execute('DELETE FROM items1')
cnxn.commit()
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO items1 ([item]) VALUES (?)', values1)
cnxn.commit()

cur.execute('DELETE FROM items2')
cnxn.commit()
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO items2 ([item]) VALUES (?)', values2)
cnxn.commit()

# IMPORT JOIN QUERY INTO PANDAS (PARENTHESES ARE REQUIRED)
query = '''SELECT * FROM (TABLE t 
        INNER JOIN items1 i1 ON t.[item] = i1.[item])
        INNER JOIN items2 i2 ON t.[item2] = i2.[item]
'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
print(df)
```

Alternative query:

```
query = '''SELECT * FROM TABLE 
        WHERE item IN (SELECT [item] FROM items1) 
          AND item2 IN (SELECT [item] FROM items2)
'''
```